# Why does variable locate before the loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Why is the position of a loop header relative to the body is different from its usual one? How come a loop variable appears before the loop? 
**The code is taken from various programs**

```
 n=reduce(operator.mul,[int(x) for x in str(n)],1)
 return value == sum(int(x) ** len(str(value)) for x in str(value))
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking about? This question doesn't make much sense as-is. Are you asking about the `for` part?

Comment: Thats syntax for list comprehension. Its not a "for" loop.

Comment: Make's perfect sense, a typical newb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, technically, not a loop. This is so-called comprehension syntax, borrowed into Python from Haskell (see comments for the full lineage). To follow traditions of math notation for sets, and distinguish a comprehension from a usual loop, loop-like enumerator comes in the end of the notation.

Find more of history of various comprehensions and generator expression  in Python here http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html

NOTE. The first of your expression contains a list comprehension, the list comprehension is the first and the most popular pythonic comprehension. The second one contains a generator expression, which, though, originally were called generator comprehension, according to PEP 289.

Comment: Haskell, ey? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#History

Comment: Exactly. According to the Python FAQ, Haskell. https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonVsHaskell